# Soundcloud authentication in electron

Tags: soundcloud, electron

I'm trying to build a Soundcloud desktop app using electron, and I'm struggling to understand how to get the authentication key. In the snippet below from the Soundcloud api they explain that you can use a "custom protocol scheme" to use as your redirect uri.

> You authenticate Mobile and Desktop Applications the same way you do
>   for Server-side Web Applications. To make the flow smoother, you can
>   use a redirect_uri with a custom protocol scheme and set your app as a
>   handler for that protocol scheme. For example, your redirect_uri could
>   be something like my-app://soundcloud/callback.
>
> [Soundcloud API authentication docs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#authentication)

Is this possible using electron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There is a repository on GitHub called Cumulus:

https://github.com/gillesdemey/Cumulus

This application is built on electron and uses the SoundCloud API, if you take a look at this file, or in the repository, you may be able to get an understanding of how it uses the API:

https://github.com/gillesdemey/Cumulus/blob/master/app/js/utils/soundcloud.js

Hope this helps